# How to change list icon of a custom list?

Tags: custom-list, csom

I wanted to change the icon in site content for a custom list in SharePoint Online. Setting the `ImageUrl` property of the list did the job. But then I discovered that this had also changed the icon for the list when adding web parts, distorting this view:

[image]

Strangely setting ImageUrl has changed two icons that need to be of different size and color. I can see on other lists that SharePoint is using two different images for this by default.

How do I properly change the list icons? Can this even be done with CSOM/JSOM? (If not, can I set the list icons back to the defaults, reverting my changes?)

Answer (score 1):

Dan, you can do the trick using CSS..

In this example i changed the default icon for the selection icon in connected web parts..

```
IMG[src*='/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif']
{
BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url('../../images/rbsel2.jpg'); /* This is the url for the image to replace the selected arrow*/
WIDTH: 16px; /*this must equal the width of your new image*/
HEIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-TOP: 16px ;
}
```

You can force a new img, width and height using CSS selectors..

PS, got this in some forum, but was long time ago and i didn't remeber the original URL, but the idea wasn't mime so i  have to give the credit for the idea to someone else that i don't know who ..